# Error when using Python's help() utility in CMD ('more' is not recognized)

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

Okay, so I try to use the `help` function of Python, but every time I type something (e.g. `help(list.append)`) I get this  error:

`'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

It works if I launch CMD as an admin, but not otherwise.
I looked up what `more` does and it has to do with Python showing documentation one page at a time rather than all at once. 
Can I somehow disable that or alternatively enable `more` for non-admin CMD windows?

Answer (score 0):

Python uses the more program to show the help text. It's saying it can't find the more program. It should be at C:\Windows\System32\more.com. You need to have C:\Windows\System32 in your PATH environment variable.

[answered back in 2011 by rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924967/using-interpreter-to-lookup-module-sys-in-python)