# "help"() function not finding documentation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

New to Python and really want to utilize the help() feature for module descriptions and such.

I initially installed anaconda3 with python 3.7, editing in VScode all on Windows7.

When I open Python and and type help('modules')

```
(base) C:\Users\Owner>python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Ana
conda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help()

Welcome to Python 3.7's help utility!

If this is your first time using Python, you should definitely check out
the tutorial on the Internet at https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/.

Enter the name of any module, keyword, or topic to get help on writing
Python programs and using Python modules.  To quit this help utility and
return to the interpreter, just type "quit".

To get a list of available modules, keywords, symbols, or topics, type
"modules", "keywords", "symbols", or "topics".  Each module also comes
with a one-line summary of what it does; to list the modules whose name
or summary contain a given string such as "spam", type "modules spam".

help> modules

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

C:\Users\Owner\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\__init__.py:13: ShimWa
rning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0.You sh
ould import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  "You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
INTEL MKL ERROR: The operating system cannot run %1. mkl_intel_thread.dll.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.

(base) C:\Users\Owner>
```

I have looked all over the web for a solution. It could have something to do with numpy so I decided to install a clean python 3.8. After the install, I now get the following for any help() lists and descriptions of the module or symbol I want a description of.

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help()

Welcome to Python 3.8's help utility!

If this is your first time using Python, you should definitely check out
the tutorial on the Internet at https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/.

Enter the name of any module, keyword, or topic to get help on writing
Python programs and using Python modules.  To quit this help utility and
return to the interpreter, just type "quit".

To get a list of available modules, keywords, symbols, or topics, type
"modules", "keywords", "symbols", or "topics".  Each module also comes
with a one-line summary of what it does; to list the modules whose name
or summary contain a given string such as "spam", type "modules spam".

help> symbols

Here is a list of the punctuation symbols which Python assigns special meaning
to. Enter any symbol to get more help.

!=                  +                   <=                  __
"                   +=                  <>                  `
"""                 ,                   ==                  b"
%                   -                   >                   b'
%=                  -=                  >=                  f"
&                   .                   >>                  f'
&=                  ...                 >>=                 j
'                   /                   @                   r"
'''                 //                  J                   r'
(                   //=                 [                   u"
)                   /=                  \                   u'
*                   :                   ]                   |
**                  <                   ^                   |=
**=                 <<                  ^=                  ~
*=                  <<=                 _

help> +
'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

help> (+)
No Python documentation found for '(+)'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.

help>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have had noting but issues from the start. I have not been able to work through any anaconda or python tutorials. This is just the most basic issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How did you install the clean Python 3.8?

Comment: Ok, I have figued out part of my issue. In 3.8, The 'more' is a .exe file in C:/windows/system32. Ill post the location of the thread tomarrow. I Had to set my PATH system variables to that address. I have not tried re installing coda yet But it cold be a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'more' is a .exe file in C:/windows/system32. I had to set my PATH system variables to that address.

Here is the thread that helped me through this:

[Using interpreter to lookup module 'sys' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924967/using-interpreter-to-lookup-module-sys-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should re install your python package.

Comment: re install anaconda and python 3.8?

Comment: Try python first

Comment: @AyushRaj What do you mean? They were using Conda at first, the other Python is one they just installed.