# ''more'' is not recognized as an internal or external or command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python

```
class human: 
    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name 


class nothuman(human): 
    def fullnameofhuman(self): 
        print(f'{self.name}')

human_being_01 = human('mohammed')
```

Whenever I'm executing this code, the following error message appears whether was on python terminal or cmd

```
print(help(nothuman))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: doesn't seem to be an issue with the code, but rather with something in your environment. What happens when you run some other kind of code?

Comment: They work normally except for help function.

Comment: the issue is not with your code. For whatever reason, 'help' tries to call 'more', and 'more' doesn't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using interpreter to lookup module 'sys' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924967/using-interpreter-to-lookup-module-sys-in-python)

Comment: One of the answers I saw said that you should have C:\Windows\System32 to your path Environment variable that's because python uses more.com app to display texts on the interpreter so before you do anything you should make sure that  C:\Windows\System32\more.com app already exists in your machine if you have any information about how to add this path to environment variable this problem will be solved and I will be so gald.